# Adjusting the size of a editorfor box using inline css or site.css file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css, razor

I have a mvc 3 app that uses Razor.There are several forms on the site where information is requested from the user. The problem is some of these boxes need to be longer than others.. I am lost on how to change the width of specific editorFor boxes using css.. 
The below box is an example of one of the boxes...

```
        <tr>

    <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.School_Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.School_Title)</td>
    <td> @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Short_Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Short_Name)</td>

  </tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered a few times in different scenarios here on SO. Basically, you cannot add CSS directly to an `EditorFor()`

**I would HIGHLY suggest using [Editor Templates](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx). It's definitely the "right" way to style your EditorFor.**

You can tell a model property to use an Editor Template in two different ways.

The first (the simplest) is to create an editor template for a certain data type - `DateTime` for example.
The second way to do it is to set it declaratively in your DataAnnotations by using a [UIHint](http://mikevdm.com/BlogEntry/Key/Using-UIHint-With-ControlParameters-in-MVC).

Alternatively, if you're hung up on using inline CSS for your Editor, you will need to use `TextBoxFor()`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.School_Title, New With {.class = "CustomCssAttribute" }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I was in the dark about editor templates even existing in mvc 3..

Answer (score 0):

School_Title is a text field. Editor for a text field will generate HTML text input element.

HTML input can be styled by adding the following into your site.css

```
input[type="text"]{
   background-color: gray;
   color: white;
}
```

This will apply to all text inputs that use site.css stylesheet.

Alternative solution is to apply a CSS class through HTML attributes. For example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.School_Title, new { @class: "myStyle" })
```

In your site.css you'll need to add your style:

```
.myStyle
{
   background-color: gray;
   color: white;
}
```

You shouldn't be scared of editors. The only way to get used to them, is to write your own editor. Write an editor that creates a div with some styling. Built-in editors for text fields are no different. They promote encapsulation and code re-usability. Eventually you should see a need to write editors for object graphs.

For example, I may have a view model that contains customer details. If I want to create or update customer details, I'll use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "Customer")`, or if I want to display details of a customer, I'll use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model, "Customer")
```

Comment: The OP says *"The problem is some of these boxes need to be longer than others"*... which means that a blanket CSS setting will not work

Comment: Just noticed your edit. Unfortunately you're wrong in the adding the `class` to the `EditorFor()` as it will not work. You have to use an `EditorTemplate` or a `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: I was aiming to give an example where we can assign a class through EditorFor. You can then change colours, size of the box etc through CSS. I can't remember whether it's EditorFor or TextBoxFor as I'm writing this in notepad, sorry.

Comment: `EditorFor` does *not* allow this. It has to be done in a template or a `TextBoxFor`... Please see my answer.